# Converting integer elements of list to a decimal in prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to convert an integer list into a decimal number but am getting an instantiation error I cannot fix.Below is my code to try to this.

```
number([X|[]],X).
number([X|XS],Y) :-
   len([X|XS],B),
   BB is B-1,
   YY is X*10^(BB),
   L is Y+YY,
   number(XS,L).
```

I am not too sure how to go over this problem. `len` is a function to return the length of the given list.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are they elements of the list just decimal digits? Prolog has a built-in `length/2` predicate for doing a list length. The other issue is the recursion is a little bit the wrong direction in your current design: you want to do `number(XS, L)` then `Y is L+YY`.

Comment: didn't know `length/2` exists.yes all elements are decimal digits @lurker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of integers that are decimal digits (e.g, having the domain of 0–9). You should be able to do something like this:

```
digits_value( Ds , V ) :-
  digits_value(Ds,0,V)
  .

digits_value( []     , V , V ) .
digits_value( [D|Ds] , T , V ) :-
  T1 is 10*T + D ,
  digits_value(Ds,T1,V)
  .
```

The nice thing about the tail recursion is that you build the result as you go. On each call, you just scale by a factor of 10 and add. You don't care about powers of 10.

To do it the way you're trying to do it, you might try reversing the list so as not to fuss with powers of 10:

```
digits_value(Ds,V) :-
  reverse(Ds,X) ,
  digits_value_x(X,V)
  .

digits_value_x([D],D).
digits_value_x([D|Ds],V) :-
  digits_value_x(Ds,T) ,
  V is 10*T + D
  .
```

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
digits_value(Ds,V) :-
  length(Ds,L) ,
  S is 10**(L-1) ,
  digits_value_x(X,S,V)
  .

digits_value_x([D],1,D).
digits_value_x([D|Ds],S,V) :-
  S1 is S / 10 ,
  digits_value_x(Ds,S1,T) ,
  V is D*S + T
  .
```